# installing english-dictionary in linux

Tags: linux

I am using redhat 5.7 linux. For several text applications, I need to look-up synonyms or meanings on web, which I do not prefer. Is there a way to install a dictionary program in linux. I gave quick search to previous SO questions, but could not find a solution. I would be grateful.

I also have access to ubuntu, so a solution for that is also fine.

Comment: Looks like this question may fit better on the Unix and Linux site.
http://unix.stackexchange.com/
  If you'd like an Ubuntu-specific answer, you can use http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: This feels awfully like a shopping and recommendation question which we don't allow on the SE sites. Have asked the unix bods if the want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aiksaurus is an adequate command line thesaurus and Babiloo would be your dictionary, but I believe you need to find a dictionary file for it to read from yourself.